# How do I centralize an ordered list?

Tags: css

I'm having problems with centralizing the text in an ordered list. It appears as it should in all browsers except for IE.

The text is centralized except for the numbers which are aligned to the far left. How do I get the numbers to centralize in Internet Explorer as well?

Here is my HTML:

```
<h2>Ordered List</h2>
<ol>
<li>Aliquam erat volutpat</li>
<li>Lacinia scelerisque lacinia quis</li>
<li>Consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
<li>Magnis dis parturient montes</li>
</ol>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
ol li { 
list-style-type:decimal; 
color:#555; 
font-size:15px; 
text-align:center; 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364836/how-to-center-ordered-list-number-in-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `list-style-position` to `inside`.