# How to number vertically aligned images within a list

Tags: html, css, image, list, html-lists

My images are ordered numerically. The number assigned is above the image.

```html
       <ol style="text-align:center;">
            <hr>
            1
            <hr>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="image1" width="30%" height="30%">
            <hr>
            2
            <hr>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="image2" width="30%" height="30%">
            <hr>
            3
            <hr>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="image3" width="30%" height="30%">
            <hr>
            4
            <hr>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="image4" width="30%" height="30%">
            <hr>
            5
            <hr>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="image5" width="30%" height="30%">
        </ol>
```

However, when I put the image into a list the number is on the left-bottom side of the image. How can I yield the initial result using a list?

Comment: Could you put this into a code snippet, please? I'm running this on Codepen, and the number is centered in the middle above the image.

Comment: **`<ol>` can only have `<li>` for children** ,  use the ol list properly and use CSS `border` instead `hr` ;) example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bZewRd

Comment: Ah, thanks. Your example is great, only if the number was above the image.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: inherit;  
}
    ol > li::before {
        content: "\A";
        white-space: pre;
    }
```

[How to center ordered list number in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364836/how-to-center-ordered-list-number-in-html)